# Looking for books with difficult exercises on Limits, Sequences & Series and Mean Value/Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I was wandering if anybody knew any books with difficult exercises on Infinite Series, Mean Value Theorem, perhaps some limits and DE's. Thanks!

Comment: Consider tagging this with reference-request as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some relevant books with challenging content only:

Andreescu : *Putnam and Beyond*

Andreescu : *Problems in Real Analysis: Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis*

Makarov : *Selected Problems in Real Analysis*

Francinou : *Oraux X-ENS: Analyse 1*

Francinou : *Oraux X-ENS: Analyse 4*

Kaczor : *Problems in Mathematical Analysis I*

Kaczor : *Problems in Mathematical Analysis II: Continuity and Differentiation*

Answer (score 1):

You can try Problems in Calculus by Sameer Bansal

Comment: Looks helpful thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

De Michele - Forti: Esercizi di analisi I. It is a quite difficult book, but I don't know whether they translated it. (It's Italian)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't find it translated but I appreciate your help!